# GNU screen quit and killall processes

Tags: terminal, gnu, tmux, gnu-screen

I've created a .screenrc config file to setup some split screen stuff for what im working on, and i've bound ctrl+d to quit it, but it only quits the screen, and leaves the actual processes running.
Heres the bind keys part of my .screenrc file atm, is there a way i can tweek it so it kills processes too?

`bindkey ^D quit`

It needs to quit and kill multiple split screens btw so that may add to the complexity of it.
Ultimately i'd like to bind it to Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D, either way a quick way to exit this script as its a custom script loading this custom .screenrc file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure if you are aware of the screen ctrl a functions

```
ctrl a c to create a new screen

ctrl a a or [0-9] to run through connections

ctrl a d to detach
```

where you can then use

```
 screen -r -d to re-attach
```

and I think you need

```
ctrl a \
```

this will attempt to quit the screen session and prompt if you wish to cancel it all

Comment: Thanks @vahid, I've tried ctrl a \ and it exits, but it doesn't seem to kill the processes it started. E.g. i have a make task running in the screen window, and i use ctrl a \ to exit, and that exits, but if i then run ps aux | grep make and i can still see the process. Is there a way to force it to kill these when i exit?

Comment: I was just testing this and I think it relates to if the task has been made into its own running pid so for example cat /etc/passwd && sleep 100 vs cat /etc/passwd && sleep 100& - where the last ampersand sets it to run as its own job ... in which case it be real hard to track.. you could screen as a new user then run pkill -U newuser

Comment: thats a great idea about opening screen with a specific user to just kill them off after, i'll do that for now thanks!

Comment: Sorry dude, was playing on mind, this one and wanted to think of alternatives since yes if I & my script it does stick around doing a ps -elf it returns 1 as master process.. so the only other think of is if you called those screen scripts something with the name that matches the screen session i.e. screen-script1.sh then when exiting run pkill -f screen which will kill screen and all of its hanging scripts